# How to achieve fast user switching with multiple graphics adapters, prevent virtual terminal switch?

Tags: linux, xorg, udev, multiseat

My boxen has two video nVidia graphics adapters which I'd like to assign to separate seats, including virtual terminals. This question most likely isn't display manager specific, but in this case I'm using lightdm-1.2.2 to set up an instance on top of a secondary video card.

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-command=X -sharevts -isolateDevice PCI:0:2:0
#xserver-layout=
xserver-config=xorg-6600.conf

[LightDM]
#start-default-seat=true
#greeter-user=lightdm
minimum-display-number=6
minimum-vt=7
```

This is how it launches:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Launching process 10099: /usr/bin/X -sharevts -isolateDevice PCI:0:2:0 :6 -config xorg-6600.conf -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:6 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

There is already another Xorg-1.12 instance running on top of the primary video card.

When I start lightdm everything is fine, because of `-sharevts -novtswitch` and both X servers display correctly on their respective monitors.

Now when I launch `/usr/libexec/lightdm/gdmflexiserver` to do fast user switching, this triggers a vt switch -> `vt8`, which is understandable. **Unfortunately this also bumps my primary video card off its vt7 display.**

How do I prevent the primary graphics adapter from switching? Would this have anything to do with the recent udev multiseat capability? Would I somehow be able to separate my sets of virtual terminals on top of separate graphics adapters?